# Regex capturing too much or not enough

Tags: php, regex

I'm having some trouble matching the below data with my regex.  I want to capture all data after the last `"-"` up until the blank line.  I've tried various contortions of modifiers and regexes but I can't seem to get it to match what I want.  I either wind up with the first line (Line 1:....) or all the lines including the rest of the document I'm pulling from.  Help please?

Data:

```
Title\n
- ---------------\n
Line 1: Some random chars//:"'\n
Line 2: Some random chars//:'"\n
Line 3: Some random chars//':"\n
Line 4: Some random chars/'/:"\n
Line 5: Some random chars//:"'\n
Line 6: Some random chars//:'"\n
\n
```

Regex:

```
/Title[\s\-]+(?P<lines>.*)/i
```

Comment: What is a `blank line` ?

Comment: @sln It's a blank line... e.g \n

Comment: There are _infinite_ possibilities of what a blank line could look like. Unfortunately, there is no regex construct for `blank lines`.

Answer (score 0):

Look for two consecutive(`\r\n\r\n`) newlines at the end of your regex:

```
preg_match_all("/Title[\s\-]+(?P<lines>.*)(?=\r\n\r\n)/msi", $input, $matches);
```

Not sure how it will be in `linux`, may be `\n\n`

Answer (score 0):

> I want to capture all data after the last "-" up until the blank line.

You can look for every characters after a "-" and a white space like this :

```
/\-\s+(.*)\s/s
```

...until another final white space.

The option :
s = Dot matches all ( http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php )

Hope this is what you was looking for.